# SQL Server : recursive aggregate information

Tags: sql-server, recursion, aggregate

I got a problem where I want to aggregate data from a tree recursively. For example I have my tasklist that looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  id int,
  parentid int,
  name varchar(256),
  status varchar(32),
  completiondate varchar(32),
  startdate varchar(32)
);

INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (1, NULL, 'clean', NULL, NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (2, NULL, 'wash', NULL, NULL, NULL)

-- insert subtasks
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (3, 1, 'vacuum', NULL, NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (4, 3, 'vacuum floor', 'completed', '2013-12-01', '2013-12-01')
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (5, 3, 'vacuum stairs', 'not done', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (6, 1, 'windows', 'completed', '2014-02-01', '2014-01-01')
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (7, 2, 'white clothes', 'completed', '2014-02-01', '2014-01-01')

INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (8, 2, 'colored clothes', 'completed', '2014-02-01', '2014-01-01')
```

And I want the task with id 3 to be like the following:

```
id   name       status           completiondate       startdate
3    vacuum     'not done'       NULL                 '2013-12-01'
```

and this result would be aggregated up to id 1:

```
id   name       status           completiondate       startdate
1    clean     'not done'        NULL                 '2013-12-01'
```

and for id 2:

```
id   name       status           completiondate       startdate
2    wash      'completed'       '2014-02-01'         '2014-01-01'
```

The logic is that if all "subtasks" (children) are status completed then take `MAX(completiondate)`, else null. And startdate would be `MIN(startdate)` of all children.

Does anyone have any clue of how to proceed? I tried with a recursive CTE but it didn't go so well. It can be up to several levels, so I guess I have to start from the bottom and aggregate up?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE, and some creative SUM():

```
;with x as (
    select *, id as root_id, name as root_name
    from tasks
    --where parentid is null
    where id = 3
    union all
    select t.*, x.root_id, x.root_name
    from tasks t
    inner join x on t.parentid=x.id
),
y as (
    select root_id, root_name, sum(case when status='not done' then 1 else 0 end) as status, 
        min(startdate) AS startdate, max(completiondate) AS completiondate
    from x
    group by root_id, root_name
)
select root_id, root_name, case when status = 0 then 'completed' else 'not done'end as status,
    startdate, case when status = 0 then completiondate else null end
from y
```